# Read the each string text from file in java

Tags: java, string, file, io

I am new in java. I just wants to read each string in java and print it on console.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("/Users/OntologyFile.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fstream));
        String data = new String();
        while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { // use if for reading just 1 line
            System.out.println(""+data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error
    }
}
```

If file contains:

```
Add label abc to xyz
Add instance cdd to pqr
```

I want to read each word from file and print it to a new line, e.g.

```
Add
label
abc
...
```

And afterwards, I want to extract the index of a specific string, for instance get the index of `abc`.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: String data = new String(); however, you haven't given it a value. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @namratashahade - Whichever answer helps, please accept and upvote the best answer. See how to upvote -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow and how to accept -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Just add a for-each loop before printing the output :-

```
while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { // use if for reading just 1 line
  for(String temp : data.split(" "))
  System.out.println(temp); // no need to concatenate the empty string.
}
```

This will automatically print the individual strings, obtained from each String line read from the file, in a new line.

> And afterwards, I want to extract the index of a specific string, for
>   instance get the index of abc.

I don't know what index are you actually talking about. But, if you want to take the index from the individual lines being read, then add a temporary variable with count initialised to 0.

Increment it till d equals `abc` here. Like,

```
int count = 0;
for(String temp : data.split(" ")){
 count++;
 if("abc".equals(temp))
  System.out.println("Index of abc is : "+count);
 System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to do two things:

1. Print all words inside the file
2. Search the index of a specific word

In that case, I would suggest scanning all lines, splitting by any whitespace character (space, tab, etc.) and storing in a collection so you can later on search for it. Not the question is - can you have repeats and in that case which index would you like to print? The first? The last? All of them?

Assuming words are unique, you can simply do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("/Users/OntologyFile.txt");
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fstream));
        String data = null;
        while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            for (String word : data.split("\\s+") {
                words.add(word);
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error
    }

    // search for the index of abc:
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        if (words.get(i).equals("abc")) {
             System.out.println("abc index is " + i);
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't break, it'll print every index of `abc` (if words are not unique). You could of course optimize it more if the set of words is very large, but for a small amount of data, this should suffice.

Of course, if you know in advance which words' indices you'd like to print, you could forego the extra data structure (the `ArrayList`) and simply print that as you scan the file, unless you want the printings (of words and specific indices) to be separate in output.

Answer (score 1):

Split the `String` received for any whitespace with the regex `\\s+` and print out the resultant data with a `for` loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    // Don't make main throw an exception

    File file = new File("/Users/OntologyFile.txt");

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String data;
        while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = data.split("\\s+");    // Split on whitespace
            for (String word : words) {             // Iterate through info
                System.out.println(word);           // Print it
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Probably best to actually have this on there
        System.err.println("Error found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()` Function available in `Class String`.. You may manipulate according to your need.

or

use `length` keyword to iterate throughout the complete **line**
and if any non- alphabet character get the `substring()`and write it to the new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
      List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
       while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { 
           for(String d : data.split(" ")) {
             System.out.println(""+d);
           }
           words.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));   
         }
    //words List will hold all the words. Do words.indexOf("abc") to get index


     if(words.indexOf("abc") < 0) {
        System.out.println("word not present");     
      } else {
       System.out.println("word present at index " + words.indexOf("abc"))
      }
```

Comment: if abc is not found in the list it will print -1. what behaviour do you want if word is not found?

Comment: Logically, that shouldn't be printed. It is not a valid index. But, it depends on you if you want to keep it as such(it is not much readable in that way).